# Linux Mint connecting to a Windows 10 shared printer

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint

Using Linux Mint different versions, Qiana is one of them.

I'm trying to print to a windows 10 shared printer, I have configured the printer via the gui, it finds the printer I see the file is received for printing in the Windows 10 computer (received has a raw file no title or other information about the print job), but the printer just blinks and doesn't print. Any ideas?

The printer only returns back to work after I delete the printer jobs.

I'm using a authenticated user to access the printer.
Linux Mint -> Windows 10 shared printer

Answer (score 0):

I disabled bidirectional support on the printer and it solved the issue. The answer was found on a online forum but do not have the link to it.